# How to create multiple model instances at once in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a method like this:

```
codes.each do |code|
  company = Company.find_or_create_by(code: code)
  company.foo = some_value
  company.bar = some_value2
  company.save
end
```

And to make it faster I want to write it with `update_all`

```
codes.each do |code|
  Company.find_or_create_by(code: code)
  Company.where(code: code).update_all(foo: some_value, bar: some_value2)
end
```

But the `find_or_create_by` run every time a SQL command.
Is there a way to create multiple model instances at once?

I want to write like `Company.create_all_if_not_exist(code: codes)`.

Answer (score 0):

I see a better way:

```
existing_companies = Company.where(code: codes)
existing_codes = existing_companies.pluck(:code) # +1 request
non_existing_codes = codes - existing_codes

attrs = {foo: some_value, bar: some_value2}

existing_companies.update_all(attrs) # +1 request

# + (codes - existing_codes) requests
non_existing_codes.each do |code|
  Company.create({code: code}.merge(attrs))
end
```